# Transaction reverting when it hits Require statement in payable function

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, payable

So briefly, when the user clicks a submit button from UI, it needs to pass a fixed price `_price` to `pay()` function (there are options to choose a fixed price on UI ex: 0.01, 0.02, 0.03). In the function, it checks if the `msg.value` is equal to the amount passed from the UI. Then the sender sends that price to the contract address and it adds up to the total contract balance. When I debug it with remix, it gives an error message when it hits `require(_price == msg.value)`

> transact to Test.pay errored: VM error: revert.
>   revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
contract Test {

    function Test() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function pay(uint _price) payable returns (bool) {
        //...

        require(_price == msg.value); // Check ether sent is matching with the price
        address(this).transfer(msg.value); // Send price to the contract address
        balanceOfContract[address(this)] += msg.value; // Store price to current contract balance

        LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I increased the gas limit just in case, but still giving me the error. Help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess I would assume that `_price` and `msg.value` are different. :-) Are you typing in the exact same number in the "value" field toward the top in Remix and in the field next to the "pay" button?

Comment: Oh, or is it possible the revert is on the following line? `address(this).transfer(msg.value)` doesn't make much sense. That has no effect, since it transfers ether from the contract to the contract, so there's no need for that line. Also, it will fail if you don't have a payable fallback function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put the exact same number in the value field (ether selected) and field next to the pay button and pressed pay button in red. Still got stuck in that `require` line. I deleted `address(this).transfer(msg.value)`

Comment: The basic code works fine for me in Remix. I added `address owner;` and deleted everything in `pay` except for the `require` and the `return` line. Then I deployed the contract using the JavaScript VM, entered `5` in both the "value" field (with the unit set to "wei") and in the field next to the red "pay" button. Then I pressed the "pay" button, and there was no error.

Comment: You are right! I changed ether to wei and it worked. Why ether is not working?

Comment: 1 ether = 1000000000000000000 wei. So if you send 1 ether, you need to pass 1000000000000000000 as the parameter to `pay`. (`msg.value` is always in wei.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the findings in the comment thread:

The issue was that the `_price` passed in to the `pay` function was being specified in ether rather than in wei. `msg.value` is always in wei, so the `require` was failing.